# How can you access the style of a root view of a split view controller in UIBuilder?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

How can you access the style of a root view of a split view controller in UIBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API access to the UISplitViewController's top-level view, all you can control are the sub-views. For those you simply adjust the style as you otherwise would any other UIView.

**edit:**

If you're attempting to change the header on the left hand side, if you have xCode 4, you can do it directly in the IB interface simply by clicking the UINavBar and changing the tint in the inspector. If you don't, you'll have to create an outlet to the UINavigationBar in your rootViewController and do something like: UINavigationBarAtTopOfRootView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1 ]

see: [UIColor Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: For the left hand side of the subview, how do you chance the color of the top bar?

Comment: if you have xCode 4, you can do it directly in the IB interface simply by clicking the UINavBar. if you don't, you'll have to create an outlet to the UINavigationBar in your rootViewController and do something like: UINavigationBarAtTopOfRootView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha] or something similar

see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIColor

Comment: I have Xcode version 3.2.5, there is a newer version of Xcode?

Comment: if you're part of the iOS development program you can download the xcode 4 beta